# Scala pickle type mismatch

Tags: scala, pickle, type-safety

I played around a bit with scala's pickle serialization, so on I had written a Netty Handler but when I try to compile the file using scalac I get an error because of an type mismatch which I can't explain myself

```
import java.util

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext
import io.netty.handler.codec.{MessageToMessageDecoder, MessageToMessageEncoder}

import scala.pickling._

import scala.pickling.binary._

import scala.pickling.json._






class PickleEncoder(format: PickleFormat = scala.pickling.binary.pickleFormat) extends MessageToMessageEncoder[AnyRef] {

  implicit val pickleFormat = format

  override def encode(implicit ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: AnyRef, out: util.List[AnyRef]): Unit = {
    val pickled: Pickle = msg.pickle
    val bytes = pickled.value match {
      case bytes: Array[Byte] => bytes
      case json: String => json.getBytes("UTF-8")
      case _ => throw PicklingException("Unable to detect pickle format")
    }
    out.add(bytes.toByteBuf)
  }


}

class PickleDecoder(format: PickleFormat = scala.pickling.binary.pickleFormat) extends MessageToMessageDecoder[ByteBuf] {

  implicit val pickleFormat = format

  override def decode(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: ByteBuf, out: util.List[AnyRef]) = {
    val bytes: Array[Byte] = msg.toBytes
    val data = format match {
      case scala.pickling.binary.pickleFormat => bytes.unpickle[AnyRef]
      case scala.pickling.json.pickleFormat => new String(bytes, "UTF-8").unpickle[AnyRef]
      case _ => throw PicklingException("Unable to detect pickle format")
    }
    out.add(data)
  }
}
```

Compile Error:

```
Error:(30, 31) type mismatch;  found   : scala.pickling.Pickle 
required: PickleEncoder.this.pickleFormat.PickleType
    val pickled: Pickle = msg.pickle
```

Any ideas what the problem is ?
                                   ^

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was a binary mismatch between scala and scala-pickle, with correct versions it compiles.